# Determining if a set of continuous and bounded functions on $\mathbb{R}$ is closed, open, and bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, normed-spaces

I wanted to know if what I have done so far is correct and how to determine if this set is open and what the closure would be. Here is the question:

Let $\mathcal{C_{b}}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ be the space of real-valued continuous and bounded functions on $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the $\sup$-norm (uniform norm). Let $A\subset\mathcal{C_{b}}$ be $$A=\left\{f\in\mathcal{C_{b}}\left(\mathbb{R}\right):0\lt f\left(x\right)\lt2,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$$ Is $A$ bounded with respect to the $\sup$-norm? Is $A$ closed? If not, what is the closure? Is $A$ open?

I said that $A$ was bounded because for every sequence $f_{n}\in A$, $f_{n}$ is in $\mathcal{C_{b}}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$, so it is bounded under the $\sup$-norm. More specifically, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, if $f_{n}\in A$, then $0\lt f_{n}\left(x\right)\lt2$ so $\|f_{n}\left(x\right)\|_{\infty}\lt2$. Thus, every sequence in $A$ is bounded, so $A$ is bounded.

I said that $A$ was not closed. For example, let $f_{n}\left(x\right)=\frac{2}{\left(nx\right)^{2}+2}$. Since $\|f_{n}\left(x\right)\|_{\infty}\lt2$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $f_{n}\left(x\right)$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$. Since $f_{n}\left(x\right)$ is continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$, then $f_{n}\in\mathcal{C_{b}}\left(\mathbb{R}\right).$ $f_{n}\in A$ because $0\lt f_{n}\left(x\right)\lt2$ for all $n$ and $x$. But, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}\left(x\right)=0$$ so its limit does not lie in $A$. Thus, $A$ is not closed.

I suspect that $$cl\left(A\right)=\left\{f\in\mathcal{C_{b}}\left(\mathbb{R}\right):0\le f\left(x\right)\le2,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$$ but am not sure how to justify this. Would it just be because $0\lt f\left(x\right)\lt2$ is an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$, so the closure of it is $0\le f\left(x\right)\le2$? I am also not sure how to determine if $A$ is open or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding $\bar A$:

(I)... For $n\in \mathbb N$ the function $g_n(y)=1+(1-1/n)(y-1)$ maps $[0,2]$ continuously onto $[1/n,2-1/n]$ and we have $\sup\{|g_n(y)-y|: y\in [0,2]\}=1/n. $

If $f:\mathbb R\to [0,2]$ is continuous then for each $n\in \mathbb N$ the function $f_n(x)=g_n(f(x))$ belongs to $A,$ and $$\|f_n-f\|=\sup_{x\in \mathbb R} |g_n(f(x))-f(x)|\leq \sup_{y\in[0,2]} |g_n(y)-y|= 1/n.$$  Therefore $f\in \bar A.$

(II)... If $f \in C_b(\mathbb R)$ and $f(x_0)\not \in [0,2]$ for some $x_0,$ then let  $r=f(x_0)-2$ if $f(x_0)>2,$ and let $r=-f(x_0)$ if $f(x_0)<0.$  Then for all $g\in A$ we have $\|f-g\|>r,$ so $f\not \in \bar A.$

From (I) and (II) we have $$\bar A=\{f\in C_b(\mathbb R): \forall x\in \mathbb R\;(f(x)\in [0,2])\}.$$

Regarding whether A is open:

Let $f(x)=e^{-|x|}.$ We have $f\in A.$ For any $r>0$ the set $B(f,r)=\{g\in C_b(\mathbb R):\|g-f\|<r\}$ is NOT a subset of $A,$  because the function $g(x)=f(x)-r/2$ belongs to $B(f,r),$ but $g(x)<0$  when $|x|>\ln (2/r).$

So $A$ is not open.